# Which type of registers is used in CPU: serial or parallel? And how to implement them in VHDL?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, cpu, register

I'm making a CPU in which the memory is represented as a two-dimensional array, using FPGA. I've come to the implementation of registers, and I need the answer to this question. I'm new to electronics, and the answers I've seen were that it depends on the bus type: whether it's a single wire or their collection.

When I choose one, can you please give me a hint on implementing it in VHDL?

Comment: How would you possibly use serial registers in a CPU??

Comment: Depends on the CPU. Serial registers use fewer valves than parallel ones. But most CPUs since the early 1950s have used parallel registers.

Comment: @Hearth there *are*... specialized serial CPUs that have 1-bit wide data paths and 32bit instructions. https://github.com/olofk/serv (Olof is a funny guy. He uses this CPU to benchmark how mighty FPGAs ares: your FPGA's corescore is simply the number of RISC-V cores you can put on there)

Comment: kenticent, almost certainly you'll simply want to use parallel registers, which is exactly what VHDL gives you when you ask for something with a bit width > 1.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The problem is I'm new to VHDL as well and I counld't find a single example of exactly parallel register. I know that there are subcategories of serial registers, depending on their inputs and outputs (parallel in, parallel out; serial in, parallel out, etc). What to do?

Comment: Maybe take a look at: http://freerangefactory.org/pdf/df344hdh4h8kjfh3500ft2/free_range_vhdl.pdf. It is a great open book to start.

Comment: @kenticent A carpenter would need to learn to use his tools before he can build something as complex as a cabinet; a hardware designer will need to learn their VHDL before they can build something as complex as a CPU. "Registers" are a very fundamental concept in HDLs, and VHDL has a pretty straightforward syntax for them.

Comment: @vangelo Thank you!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Is it just a std_logic_vector? o_O

Comment: Using serial vs parallel techniques is common in fpga as you trade performance and resource usage. If you wabt a 32 bit alu you can choose from using a 1 bit alu clocked 32 times, a 4 bit alu clocked 8 times up to a 32 bit in one clock. Regarding registers, actual registers are a precious commodity in an fpga - each slice might only have one, so in order to have an efficient design, you would use wisely. In terms of resource, you have ram blocks that usually are used for a register file simply because they are a better use of resource.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you're coming from with respect to 'serial' registers. Generally, in a CPU nowadays these will be parallel, and usually some multiple of the machine's natural word width.

As to how you implement them...

Within a CPU, the local register set will be designed for low latency and for speed.  This structure is sometimes called a *register file*, and it may have multiple read and write ports to support fast access to multiple operands at once. It may very well be constructed from D flops or latches, and also have bypass logic for when the read and write pointers are the same to eliminate an extra cycle of latency.

Bigger memories would tend to use FPGA RAM resources rather than D flops. The FPGA libraries offer different options for implementing RAM, including block RAM or distributed RAM (that is, repurposed LUTs), or honest-to-dog registers like for register files.

These RAM types are most easily used as parameterized macros, with synthesis taking care of the rest. Your tool chain offers various ways to make the instantiation templates. In Vivado for example, you can create the RAM as a GUI block design, then instance that in your code using the generated VHDL template for it. If you're relatively new to HDL coding this is an easy way to go.